# web form ssrs report date icon not displaying

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have an ssrs 2008 r2 report that has a date icon on 2 of the parameters that are dates that runs on an ssrs 2012 report server. This report is accessed by running a vb.net 2010 web form application via a report view control.
The date icon works is displayed when the ssrs 2010 report is accessed by the current version of Mozilla Firefox.
However when the report is accessed by Microsoft Edge or Chrome, the date icon is not displayed. The what is displayed in the default date/time parameter.
Thus can you tell me what I can do to make the date icon on the date parameters show when Microsoft Edge or Chrome?

Comment: SSRS 2008 R2 seems to work well only with Internet Explorer. Had the same issue trying to use other browsers where it shows the date and time as text box for the parameter instead of the date picker. I think the only option is to upgrade to a newer version of report server.. 2016 did the trick for me.

Comment: So no other browsers worked for you?

Comment: No.. just IE. wouldn't work on Edge either. Its the way the web parts are rendered